# How to stream to my smartphone only what I see inside the bluestacks window

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, bluestacks, ip-address, screen-mirroring

I've just installed **Bluestacks** on my PC because I wanted to run whatsapp inside it. I have two whatsapp account. The first one on my smarthphone and the second one inside the bluestacks emulator. I want to do this because till now I used **whatsapp desktop** on my PC instead of using it directly on my smartphone. But the problem was that often **the connection was lost** and above all whatsapp for the smartphone eats a **lot of battery** from the phone. So I had the idea to use it directly inside the **android emulator**. NOW,a problem arises : when I'm at home,I kill **whatsapp** on my phone and I use that installed on the **android emulator**. BUT when I'm **out of my home**,I would like to see what my friends are saying in one of the two accounts. So,I have installed the **"screen stream mirroring"** app inside bluestacks. It says that the mirroring address is **"http://10.0.2.15:5000/screen"**. I tried to connect a web browser from the pc and from the smartphone to that address but it refuses the connection. I have also registered a new **dyndns account** and I have installed a **dns manager** inside bluestacks because I wanted to point the **address "10.0.2.15"** to a domain name,but it didn't work. It says : **"wrong ip address"**. I know that I could install a screen stream application directly on the host OS (Windows 10 in my case),but this has a big dis advantage : I should keep the **bluestacks window** opened and it takes a lot of space from my screen. I have also tried to run **teamviewer** on the bluestacks side and on the smartphone side,but I don't like this solution,because everytime I should understand where the pointer is positioned and I should move it exactly where I would like it to be. I would like also say that for me it's not useful at all using two android remote applications which works only inside the **same network**,because when I go out of my home usually I use the **mobile connection** that I have on my phone and not the wi-fi connection that's inside my house. So,the question is : how can I stream to my smartphone (samsung note 3) only what I see inside the **bluestacks window** ?

Comment: There are a number of separate issues within your question. If you were trying **address "10.0.2.15"** did you find/read: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking or [ADB Bluestacks - Connect 2 PC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30962481/295004)

Comment: excuse me,but I don't understand how make it works. I'm running the trivial port forwarding on windows 10 like this : > trivial_portforward.exe 9999 127.0.0.1 5555 but inside bluestacks the IP number is again : 10.0.2.15 and it says that the screen stream mirroring APP is listening at : http://10.0.2.15:5000/screen ; since the IP number of Windows 10 is : 192.168.1.2 but when I open the address http://192.168.1.2:5000/screen ; on Windows it says : connection rejected...

Comment: I believe you should testing with a different device on your home network. The point of port forwarding is to connect to your emulator from outside of the computer running it. Windows firewall/anti-virus may be blocking the port. You should easily find references on the subject online via your favorite search engine as it is not Android specific.

Comment: what I don't understand is which port should I use on the host OS...I'm using 5555,BUT the port used by the mirroring APP is 5000...does it matter if they are different ?